# How to use an enum as a method parameter in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, enums, thymeleaf

I am trying to invoke a method that takes an enum as a parameter from my Thymeleaf template. The enum is very straightforward:

```
public enum Language {
  C,
  JAVA,
  DOTNET
}
```

The method being invoked is equally simple:

```
public int count(Language l) {
  return counter.get(l);
}
```

And the call in the template is pretty vanilla too: `entry.value` refers to a `DTO` object that has the `count(Language)` method:

```
<td th:text="${entry.value.count(T(com.sample.Language).C)}" />
```

But when I try to load the template, I get this error: `EL1004E: Method call: Method count(com.sample.Language) cannot be found on type com.sample.DTO`. But if I provide a method in the `DTO` class that accepts a `String` and then converts it to the equivalent `Language` enum entry, all is good:

```
public int count(String lang) {
  return count(Language.valueOf(lang));
}
```

This seems contradictory. On the one hand, the error text says that Thymeleaf is looking for a method with a `Language` parameter, but then it actually invokes the method that has a `String` parameter. Is it possible to not need the `String` flavor of the `count` method in my `DTO` object?

Comment: Have you tried using org.thymeleaf.context.Context? That worked for me. Doing context.setVariable("variableName", Language.C) and then passing "${variableName}" into your template

Answer (score 1):

I commented on your question with a suggestion but have found a solution to your problem.

I read the documentation in https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html which states that:

```
"<span th:text="${book.author.name}">
```

The expression above is equivalent (both in OGNL and SpringEL) to:

```
((Book)context.getVariable("book")).getAuthor().getName()"
```

I then tried:

```
context.setVariable("entry", YourDTOClass)
```

Then using:

```
"${entry.count(@com.sample.Language@C)}"
```

obtained the correct result

Comment: That seems like an ugly workaround for what should be a simple task, and doesn't seem to really be answering the question. Where would the `context.setVariable` call be? In the template? For now I've moved on with a shrug.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by an ugly workaround here. Where are you getting your variables from such as "entry.value"? In all examples I have worked with previously, you need to create a context and pass variables into this context. Then use the template engine with this context to process the template. Based on that, this would be a normal approach to fixing the problem not an ugly workaround. Like such:

templateEngine.process(template, context)